# I keep getting duplicate results

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm new to SQL and I'm using Oracle Apex. I am trying to run the following query:

```
Select COMPANIES.COMP_NO as "Company Id", COMP_NAME as Company",
OPEN_START_DATE as "Start Date", OPEN_TITLE as "Opening Title", 
QF_CODE as "Required Qualification" 
From OPENINGS, COMPANIES
Where COMP_ADDRESS='Auckland'
AND OPEN_START_DATE Between '12/01/2016' AND '12/31/2016';
```

I know there should only be four returned results but I keep getting duplicates of the same entry. What am I doing wrong?? I believe it must be something to do with my table connections... Thanks

Comment: Please post the structure of the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    c.comp_no,
    c.comp_name,
    o.start_date,
    o.open_title 
from 
    companies c 
    join openings o on o.comp_no=c.comp_no 
where 
    start_date between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-07';
```

use join instead of selecting it in the from clause.